# Help with debugging Error in android custom component EditText

Tags: android

UPDATE

making the inner class 'static' fixed it

---

Please help me find out what the error is in the case below. I have a custom EditText inside an activity which implements the OnKeyListener. It is implemented as an inner class of the Activity

The reason i override plain TickerEditText to parent EditText is because in future i might modify EditText and also wanted to attach a OnKeyListener always to it.

I don't want to do this in Activity's onCreate().

Code compiles fine but I'm having runtime error when the application launches and inflates the view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<view
    class="com.example.android.ticker.TickerActivity$TickerEditText" 
    android:id="@+id/tickerText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="Something !!"
/>
<com.example.android.ticker.customListView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tickerListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/customListView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Usage
    public class TickerActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticker);

    /** Get Reference to UI objects */
    mTickerListView = (TickerListView)findViewById(R.id.tickerListView);
    mTickerEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tickerText);
    ...
}

...
...
...
...

public class TickerEditText extends EditText implements OnKeyListener {

    public TickerEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                 //something
                 return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even if making it static fixed it, you should really move that class to its own java file.

Comment: @dmon - Yeap you are right., i was about to do that, just was wondering if it was fine to have it like an inner class, and since it did not work, was digging into it as to why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making the inner class 'static' fixed it

Also moved it as a separate class and called it using